# How to properly sort away contacts with SQL?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have two methods of subtracting subscribers, when generating a new segment. Simplistically, it looks as follows:

**Method A:**

```
SELECT SubscriberKey, ... other fields
FROM TableX
WHERE SubscriberKey NOT IN (Select SubscriberKey from TableY)
```

**Method B**

```
SELECT a.SubscriberKey, ... other fields
FROM TableX a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(Select 1 from TableY b WHERE a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey)
```

---

Which is the best performing way in terms of the Markteting Cloud database?

Comment: ===> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: in my experience, method B preforms just as well as a left join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and check for where the values from Y are empty. Using the other two methods would probably time out as your table scales, as they attempt for join via cartesian coordinates for the whole table.